# How can i show connection status in real time on my form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating an OPC client, that reads data from the server. I need to show status of connection with server in real time on my form. Can this be done?

For example:

```
private void checkStatus()
{
   testValue.Text = cl.GetConnectionState().ToString();
}
```

cl.GetConnectionState() - method that shows connection status.

Comment: You can add a timer, which will check the status on a given period of time. Say you check the connection every 2 seconds or any arbitrary period of time depending on the particular implication.

Comment: Oh, right! I didnt thought about it. Thanks! I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a timer to call that function. Function itself is fine, and should update the status correctly.

Although, if you want to do it right, I will say put this code in `StateChange` event handler. That way, your code will not run this function forever, and instead wait for the state to change.

Comment: Yes! Thank you and Gnqz for answer, i already tried it. It works great!